# ios 11 UIFileSharingEnabled is gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

So I have this secret calculator app where users can store their private phones in my apps documents folder. If they wanted to move files from their iPhone/iPad to their PC/Mac then they would connect their device to iTunes, select my app and move files to & from their devices. They have been doing that for years. 
Today I found out that this UIFileSharingEnabled has been removed in iOS 11, since iTunes cannot be used for file sharing. The whole reason for my app (and tons of others on the app store) was that the users files were hidden from others and the only way they could get to it was using a passcode or finger print within my app ... and of course through itunes sharing.

I can add the following keys to my app plist file but that will make all of the users "secret" photos available from my app into Apple's default files app. I don't want that. Defeats the purpose of my app.

What exactly are my options now, if any, for file sharing?

[image]

Comment: please check this one https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/

Comment: @casillas - Right there is the problem "Understand that any files you place in your Documents folder will be visible within the Files apps" which will render my app pretty much useless

Comment: @casilias where you able to find a way around it?